# Refresh html mode angular app with deep linking

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, routes, requirejs, single-page-application

Like many before me, I am struggling to get page refresh working with my angular app.

I am using angular/require/webapi. I extended this from the [angular phone tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)

I placed this project on [github](https://github.com/dan-markovitch/Single-Page-Angular) as well

Here is where I currently sit.

I have the routes setup. They are in html mode. They work on site navigation.
Refreshing was causing problems. I setup code Gobal.asax.cs to reroute failures to index.html. The base page (/phones) is able to refresh. The error comes in when one refreshes the details page (phones/motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi).

Here is my routes code

```
define(['angular', 'app', 'angularRoute'], function (angular, app)
{
    'use strict';

    var myApp = app.config(['$routeProvider', '$provide', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $provide, $locationProvider) {

        //$provide.decorator('$sniffer', function ($delegate) {
        //    $delegate.history = false;
        //    return $delegate;
        //});

        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                redirectTo: '/phones'
            })

            .when('/phones', {
                templateUrl: '../Web/Templates/partials/_phones.html',
                controller: 'PhoneList'
            })

            .when('/phones/:phoneId', {
                templateUrl: '../Web/Templates/partials/_phone-detail.html',
                controller: 'PhoneDetail'
            });
            //.otherwise({
            //    redirectTo: '/phones'
            //});


        // enable html5Mode for pushstate ('#'-less URLs)
        //$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    }]);

    return myApp;
});
```

My global.asax.cs

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private const string ROOT_DOCUMENT = "index.html";

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }



    protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = Request.Url.LocalPath;
        string[] newURL = new string[1];
        newURL[0] = ROOT_DOCUMENT;
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Context.Server.MapPath(url)))
            Context.RewritePath(ROOT_DOCUMENT);
    }
}
```

And my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Angular-RequireJS sample app</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--<script data-main="Scripts/app/main" src="Scripts/lib/require.js"></script>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="Content/css/app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="Content/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="Content/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
    <base href="/">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <p>Single Page Web Ap</p>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <script data-main="Scripts/app/main" src="Scripts/lib/require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

This should solve the issue - change the constant definition:

```
private const string ROOT_DOCUMENT = "/index.html";
// instead of this
// private const string ROOT_DOCUMENT = "index.html";
```

Also check it here: [How to: Configure your server to work with html5Mode](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#user-content-how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) *(scroll down to `ASP.Net C# Rewrites`)* see that snippet:

```
private const string ROOT_DOCUMENT = "/default.aspx";

protected void Application_BeginRequest( Object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    string url = Request.Url.LocalPath;
    if ( !System.IO.File.Exists( Context.Server.MapPath( url ) ) )
        Context.RewritePath( ROOT_DOCUMENT );
}
```

Note, I would also suggest to change the `Application_BeginRequest` to properly handle API requests like this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var path = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
   var isApi = path.StartsWith("/api", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

   if (isApi)
   {
       return;
   }
   ...
```